# How to add an UIButton to placemark? ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, mkannotation, mkannotationview

How do I add a button to my placemarks and then get it to push onto a view controller?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set "More" logo in navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Navigation"]];

    appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // Set longatude and latitude to tyne and wear
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(54.995184, -1.566699);

    // Set span to cover area
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.5);

    // Set region
    MKCoordinateRegion regionToDisplay = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
    [self.nearbyMapView setRegion: regionToDisplay];

    for (int i = 0; i < [[appDelegate offersFeeds] count]; i++)
    {

        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

        NSString *plotAddress = [[[appDelegate offersFeeds] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"addressline"];
        NSString *plotTitle = [[[appDelegate offersFeeds] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"title"];


        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:plotAddress completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
            {
                CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithPlacemark:topResult];

                // Set title
                MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
                pa.coordinate = placemark.location.coordinate;
                pa.title = plotTitle;

                // Add placemark to map
                [self.nearbyMapView addAnnotation:pa];

            }
        }];
    }
}
```

I've had a look at `MKAnotationView` but struggling to understand how to get this working with `CLPlacemark`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this before you add mapview to self.view

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
    annotation.coordinate = yourCoordinate;
    annotation.title = @"Title";
    annotation.subtitle = @"SubTitle";
    [mapView1 addAnnotation:annotation];
}


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 

        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"identifier";
        pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) 
        {
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

            UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

            //Accessoryview for the annotation view in ios.
            pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
       pinView.annotation = annotation;
    return pinView;
} 

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

    //Put your button stuff here...

}
```

I hope it is useful to you

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Simply adding these two methods to my code won't add the button. What needs to be done in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: @user2920762: You need to to add button in Annotation view correct?

Comment: After searching on the internet for MKAnnotationView I understand how the above code works. However my pins still show on the map with there title as all set in viewDidLoad but still no button to the right of the caption. Its like your suggestion is not been called.